# How to implement config driven layouts in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to Flutter, so want to know how can we achieve this. The idea is to render dynamic layouts on any given page by fetching its corresponding JSON in the start of application/before navigation. This can be done in React / React Native as it allows to dynamically load the component as per key value mapping(string key to Component).

JSON is nested and preferably in this kind of JS format,

```
{
component: {
  widget_name: 'Page1' // Should map to predefined widget name Page1 in my Flutter code
  data: {
    title: 'Something',
    ...
  }
  styles: {
   paddings: 4,
   ... 
  },
  children: {
    row: [
      ...same structure as parent,
      ...same structure as parent,
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) portal for your understanding. Copy paste here your json and name of the model. Then you can generate dart model file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Dart model would exist in the code, that's right. But how to map my data with this model, so that I can change the layouts based on my configuration? My configuration would have layout structure of app and data. Then I would build a parser in dart code to read this layout structure and map the widget names to the corresponding widget components.